# Desktops on demand windows managers?`

Tags: window-manager, macosx, virtualdesktop

Are there any window managers that function like OS X's? I'm looking to be able to full screen apps and move back and forth between them. I would want to start with one virtual desktop and then I could create more on demand. I know I can specify more virtual desktops but I would like to find a on demand approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnome Shell does all that. It always has exactly one empty workspace (so if you add a window to it, a new empty workspace is created). Note that this is the default - you can configure a static workspace listing via `gnome-tweak-tool`. I am able to drag full screen windows around in the Overview mode - this helps me start games in one workspace and drag them elsewhere.